# Value of omega from forced response V0

Tags: ac, inductance, phasor, conductance

[image: figure]

Based on figure.

Maybe a simple question, but I'd like to know why that if forced  response is zero, then

$$\omega L = \frac{1}{\omega C}$$

where \$L\$ is the inductance and \$C\$ is the capacitance.

Where in this case, \$\omega\$ can be solved for to obtain the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Ohm's Law $$v_o = IZ$$ where \$Z = Z_L + Z_C\$ is the combined impedance of the inductor and capacitor. You have a non-zero voltage source so you have a non-zero current \$I\$ through this impedance \$Z\$. In order to have \$v_o = 0\$ you therefore need $$Z = Z_L + Z_C = j\omega L + \frac{1}{j\omega C} = 0$$

If you simplify this equation you will arrive at $$\omega L = \frac{1}{\omega C}$$ as explained by Dave Tweed.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. With that said, the current is equal at all points in order to apply Ohm's law? Initially, I thought of using voltage division to solve this, but the approach is more complex..

Comment: @VeeJeyVee There is only one loop in the circuit so the current is equal at all nodes. The current will of course vary with time since the voltage source varies with time, but at any point in time the current is equal at all nodes.

Answer (score 3):

Your equation is incomplete. The actual equation is based on the sum of the impedances being zero, and to do this properly, you need to account for the complex nature of the impedances:

$$Z_L + Z_C = 0$$

$$j \omega L + \frac{1}{j \omega C} = 0$$

If you multiply through by *j*, you get:

$$ -1 \omega L + \frac{1}{\omega C} = 0$$

Which you can then rewrite as your equation:

$$\omega L = \frac{1}{\omega C}$$

Comment: I think the question is asking why this equation has to hold true in order to have \$v_o = 0\$.

Comment: Okay, I get that. Thank you. But why is the sum of the impedances zero? I'm thinking it has something to do with vo=0..?